# Problem with custom layout into another layout, layout doesn't show in app and design mode

Tags: android-studio, layout, customization, android-custom-view, android-xml

So, when i click on button called calendar on main activity it should open new activity (Second screen) with part of calendar which i made (custom_calendar layout). However, it open to me only empty activity. I already tried to make changes in style.xml, clean and rebuild project, but it doesn't change anything.
Link to my app on BitBucket is down below.

https://bitbucket.org/Nike50/app/src/master/

Comment: Relevant code should be included in the question instead of linked to an external website.

Answer (score 0):

Please change **CustomCalendarView** Class as per below

```
public class CustomCalendarView extends LinearLayout {
    private static final int MAX_CALENDAR_DAYS = 42;
    ImageView backBtn, nextBtn;
    TextView CurrentDate;
    GridView gridViewCalendar;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    Context myContext;

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat yearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Events> eventsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.myContext = context;
        InitializeLayout();
        SetUpCalendar();
        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                SetUpCalendar();
            }
        });
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                SetUpCalendar();
            }
        });
    }

    private void SetUpCalendar() {
        String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        CurrentDate.setText(currentDate);
    }

    public void InitializeLayout() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_calendar, this);
        nextBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.forwardButton);
        backBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.previousButton);
        CurrentDate = view.findViewById(R.id.currentDate);
        gridViewCalendar = view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    }
}
```

It's Running well

[image]

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: Now, even doesn't open activity, app get crashed @HardikTalaviya

Comment: @NikicaRadić Are you copy this class?

Comment: You are use ImageButton object for backBtn & nextBtn but in xml you are take ImageView So,replace ImageButton to ImageView in this class.

Comment: Please find  attach image in my answer

Comment: @NikicaRadić Solved your problem?